# input variables in R functions from third party libraries

Tags: r, statistics

I am a reasonably proficient python programmer messing around with some R.

On this website, for the third party library `ICC`, I'm confused about input variables for the function `ICCest`.

Located here: 
http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ICC/docs/ICCest

I can use:

```
ICCest(Chick, weight, data=ChickWeight, CI.type="S")
```

And I got this to work. Chick and weight are column names for the data frame variable called ChickWeight. All is well and good.

Except, that, what type of variables are "Chick" and "weight"?? They aren't in my R namespace. They aren't strings because they don't have quotes around them.

Doing:

```
ICCest(Chick, "weight", data=ChickWeight, CI.type="S")
```

yields:

```
In ICCest(Chick, "weight", data = ChickWeight, CI.type = "S") :
  passing a character string to 'y' is deprecated since ICC vesion 2.3.0 and will not be supported in future versions. The argument to 'y' should either be an unquoted column name of 'data' or an object
```

So again in my nice friendly python land you can't pass in unquoted characters strings that are not objects in your namespace so I am quite confused.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the function's code by typing `ICCest` (without the parantheses):

```
> ICCest
Object with tracing code, class "functionWithTrace"
Original definition:
function (x, y, data = NULL, alpha = 0.05, CI.type = c("THD", "Smith")){
square <- function(z) {
    z^2
}
icall <- list(y = substitute(y), x = substitute(x))
if (is.character(icall$y)) {
    warning("passing a character string to 'y' is deprecated since ICC vesion 2.3.0 and will not be supported in future versions. The argument to 'y' should either be an unquoted column name of 'data' or an object")
    if (missing(data)) 
        stop("Supply either the unquoted name of the object containing 'y' or supply both 'data' and then 'y' as an unquoted column name to 'data'")
    icall$y <- eval(as.name(y), data, parent.frame())
} ...
```

what happens after the `square` function block, is that the input is stored in `icall` in a *parse tree*, which you can think of as a set of unevaluated *expressions*. So there's no error when you pass plain `weight` without the quotation marks, because at this point, there hasn't been an attempt to evaluate the expressions yet. (I'm a bit unsure about this last statement. I hope someone can confirm if it is technically correct)

Inside the `if` block (where your warning is raised), you can see that they are using `eval` to update the local variable `icall$y`. What `eval` does is essentially evaluating an expression within an environment. Specifically, in the environment of a dataframe, the column names are considered part of the environment.

Now it says in the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html), that `eval` takes an *expression* as its first input. This is why `y` is cast to an object with `as.name` before being passed to `eval` (remember that we are in the `if` block for string input `y`)

`eval(expr, envir = parent.frame(),...)`

And expressions and strings are different in R. So in the last line of code shown above, the `y` input (here, `weight`) is being evaluated in the `data` environment --which, here, is `ChickWeight`.

To get a better feeling, try this:

```
> eval(weight, ChickWeight)
Error in eval(weight, ChickWeight) : object 'weight' not found
```

But if you make an unevaluated expression first, it will work:

```
> expr <- quote(weight)
> eval(expr, ChickWeight)
```

Here, `quote` is doing roughly the same thing as `substitute` in the 4th line of the function. Check [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substitute.html) for more on  quote and substitute\.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing your y as a quoted string. The function doesn't appear to require quoted strings for variable names.  Doing

```
str(ChickWeight)
```

will give you the types for the variables.  They aren't in a 'name space' because they are variable names in the data.frame ChickWeight.